# Is there a wa to execute PowerShell script then a Node script within (task.json) for Custom Task?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am creating a Custom Azure DevOps Task to replace my task group.  I have my custom task working for straight PowerShell now, but I am also trying to integrate a 'Standard' task (Publish Build Artifacts) within the task.  To do this I have added the azure-pipelines-tasks repo as a submodule of my project and I am compiling the task that I need and copying the output to my task.

The way the script is designed to work is run some PowerShell actions then run the "Publish Build Artifacts" js script.

The problem is when I run Node "publishbuildartifacts.js" from within the PowerShell script, it cannot read the task.json file correctly to get the info it requires, even though its within the same folder.

The only way I have been able to get "publishbuildartifacts.js" to run correctly is a direct call within the task.json.

I'm ok with this approach except for I need to run my PowerShell script before this action.

The issue I have been having is when I have the PowerShell action and the Node action within the execution action it will only run he node component, and when I add "platforms": ["windows"] to the PowerShell component; only the PowerShell will be ran and not the Node.

How can I get them to run in the order specified and in series?

I have also tried the "prejobexecution" and "postjobexecution" but that is now how I want the task to work.

```
"execution":  {
    "PowerShell3": {
        "target": "ABS-Report_tasks.ps1",
        "platforms": [                           
            "windows"
            ]
    },
    "Node":  {
        "target": "publishbuildartifacts.js",
        "argumentFormat":  ""
     }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an approach to group tasks. Take a look at the info below, see the article for full details.

[Visual Studio Code Tasks and Split Terminals](https://dev.to/pzelnip/visual-studio-code-tasks-and-split-terminals-2ghk)

```
{
    "label": "Run Server",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "${config:python.pythonPath} manage.py runserver --noreload",
    "presentation": {
        "group": "groupServerStuff"
    }
},
```

> All tasks with the same group will open up as another split terminal
>   pane in the same terminal window. Very nice.
>
> rather than start each task individually, is there a way to have tasks
>   "call" or "spawn" other tasks...

```
{
    "label": "Run Server",
    "dependsOn": [
        "Run TCP Server",
        "Run Django Server",
        "Tail Log File"
    ]
},
{
    "label": "Run Django Server",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "${config:python.pythonPath} manage.py runserver --noreload",
    "presentation": {
        "group": "groupServerStuff"
    }
},
{
    "label": "Run TCP Server",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "${config:python.pythonPath} scripts/tcp_server.py",
    "presentation": {
        "group": "groupServerStuff"
    }
},
{
    "label": "Tail Log File",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "tail -f /tmp/logfile.txt",
    "presentation": {
        "group": "groupServerStuff"
    }
},
```

***Update for OP for***

Interesting, but will it work for VSTS custom tasks within the execution block. The example is for VSCode. Because these are not tasks and not terminal windows I dont know how this would register in the series of execution I am trying to accomplish.

You did not indicate that this was for VSTS, and since you hit up this PowerShell Q&A, the assumption was VSCode.

Now, all that being said. I've never tried this in VS/VSTS proper, just VSCode. There are those using VSCode for VS builds.

There are several articles on the web on that topic as well. Yet, a quick search shows that task groups were added to VSTS.

[See: Visual Studio Team Services: Create and use task groups](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2016/09/visual-studio-team-services-create-and.html)

… though it's only showing how to do this via the GUI.

Comment: Interesting, but will it work for VSTS custom tasks within the execution block.  The example is for VSCode.  Because these are not tasks and not terminal windows I dont know how this would register in the series of execution I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

May i know which agent pool did you use for your pipeline? Azure Pipeline allows running cross-platform scripts.Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/cross-platform-scripting?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

There is another workaround for you. You can add a command in you powershell script to run publishbuildartifacts.js such as `node publishbuildartifacts.js`.

Comment: Currently I am using a Windows 2017 agent, but I will want to make this work cross-platform.  I have used the 'node publishbuildartifacts.js' from powershell but the script is trying to access our task.json file to read inputs but it cant pull in the values for some reason.  I believe it can only get the values then its called through the task.json file.